# « Cacher quelque chose à quelqu'un » ou « de quelqu'un » ?

Tags: prépositions

J'hésite sur la traduction de « a secret that he wants to hide from his brothers ».

Ma première idée était :

> un secret qu'il veut cacher de ses frères

Mais j'hésite avec :

> un secret qu'il veut cacher à ses frères

J'ai le sentiment que l'usage de « de » donne le sens « tout faire pour éviter que ses frères ne le découvrent » avec le but de le « protéger » donc. Respectivement, j'ai l'impression que l'usage de « à » signifie juste « ne pas leur dire ».

Dans le contexte, le sens serait plutôt « protéger », d'où ma première idée. Mais je ne sais pas si c'est correct.

Donc mes questions sont :

- Est-ce que les 2 prépositions sont possibles ?
- Si oui, est-ce que la nuance que je perçois est fondée ?
- Sinon, quelle est la bonne façon de dire ?

Merci.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

« Cacher quelque chose à quelqu'un » est l'unique possibilité. « *Un secret qu'il veut cacher à ses frères* » est correct. Pour éviter la redondance sémantique de *secret* et *cacher*, on peut préférer « *un secret qu'il ne veut pas partager avec ses frères* ».

On notera qu'en tant que verbe pronominal « se cacher de quelqu'un » est [mentionné dans le TLF](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/cacher), mais son emploi est vraiment exceptionnel. Dans un contexte non littéraire, *se cacher* est le plus souvent employé sans complément (indirect) ; en général on précise séparément la raison.

Comment: Je ne trouve pas « se cacher de quelqu'un » particulièrement littéraire. « Se cacher de quelque chose », peut-être.

Answer (score 2):

Les nuances fournies par le Littré, uniquement pour la forme pronominale  :

> - Se *cacher à*, fuir, éviter. Se cacher au monde.
> - Se *cacher à* soi-même, s'ignorer soi-même.

... on *se* cache pour ne pas être vu ou découvert par l'autre (qui peut être soi-même comme dans le second exemple)

> - Se *cacher de* quelqu'un, lui cacher ce qu'on dit, ce qu'on fait.
> - Se *cacher de* quelque chose, n'en pas convenir, le tenir secret.

... on cache ce que l'on sait, on se tait.

---

Développement ajouté en annexe pour l'utilisation de *de*

1. CACHER UNE CHOSE, SE CACHER *D*'UNE CHOSE.
    Tous deux expriment qu'on tient secrète une chose.

   - Je cache le dessein que j'ai, veut dire simplement que je le dérobe à la connaissance des autres.
   - Si je dis : je me cache *du* dessein que j'ai, à l'idée simple se trouve ajoutée *l'idée qu'il y aurait quelque honte, quelque dommage, quelque inconvénient à le divulguer*.
   - Un dessein qu'on ne cache pas est un dessein qu'on laisse manifeste à tous les yeux ; un dessein dont on ne se cache pas, est un dessein qu'on n'a aucun motif de crainte, de honte, de blâme pour ne pas avouer ouvertement.

Answer (score 0):

Comme l’ont dit les autres, seule la forme pronominale est suivie de *de*, la forme non pronominale ne peut être suivie que de la préposition *à*.

Cela dit, je crois qu’il existe un cas où l’on cache *de* quelqu’un :

> On cache *quelque chose* à quelqu’un.
>
> On cache quelqu’un de quelqu’un d’autre.

En somme, ça dépend du COD.

Non ?